# Using indexOf method to find value in a 2D array

Tags: javascript, indexing

I want to ask a question that I have about a 2D array in JavaScript, similar to this:

```
var array = [[2,45],[3,56],[5,67],[8,98],[6,89],[9,89],[5,67]]
```

That is, on every index, I have an array as well.

Suppose that I have a value in my second index like `56`, and I want the corresponding 1st index (i.e. 3 in above example).

I can do it using a loop (if no other option), but is there any better way?

Also, I know `indexOf` method in JavaScript, but it's not returning the index when I call it like this:

```
array.indexOf(56);
```

Any insight will be helpful.

Answer (score 14):

Use some iterator function.

`filter` allows you to iterate over an array and returns only the values when the function returns `true`.

Modern browsers way:

```
var arr = array.filter( function( el ) {
    return !!~el.indexOf( 56 );
} );
console.log( arr ); // [3, 56]
console.log( arr[ 0 ] ); // "3"
```

Legacy browsers way, using jQuery:

```
var arr = $.filter( array, function() {
    return !!~$.inArray( 56, $( this ) );
} );
console.log( arr ); // [3, 56]
console.log( arr[ 0 ] ); // "3"
```

Comment: For legacy browsers, use a for loop, not `$.filter`

Comment: What does !!~ do? (I'm new to JS and have never seen it before!)

Comment: @Tom If the `indexOf` returns `0` (the first element in the array) it will still fire `true` as `~` turns `0` into `-1` the first `!` turns `-1` into a boolean value `false` and the second `!` turns the `false` value into `true`. Steps shown [here](http://jsbin.com/EziLogA/1/edit?js,console).

Answer (score 6):

You could do like this:

```
var ret;
var index = array.map(function(el){return el[1];}).indexOf(56);
if (index !== -1) {
  ret = array[index][0];
}
```

Comment: `indexOf` is not supported by all browsers either :-)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Yep, that's it, so if op use `.indexOf`, he just could use `Array.map`.

Comment: I don't really get your solution however. You're just returning a new array with the second value of the inner arrays, but OP wants the first value. For example, he wants "3" back in this case.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I missed that, thought he wanted the index.

Comment: No problem :-) I prefer my answer though :(

Answer (score 1):

`array.indexOf( x )` returns the position of `x` in the array, or -1 if it is not found. In your 2D array this is useless, since 56 isn't in array; it is in an array which is contained in `array`.

You will have to loop over the first array, then use `indexOf` to check each sub-array.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have flexibility with the data structure, the feature you are emulating is that of a dictionary. Consider switching to a javascript associative array: {3:56, 2:45, 5:67,...}

Answer (score 1):

I found that in IE6 at least (I'm not sure about the more recent versions), the built-in Array type didn't have an indexOf method.  If you're testing in IE, perhaps that's why you couldn't get started.  I wrote this little addition to include in all my code:

```
if(!Array.prototype.indexOf){
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function(obj){
        for(var i=0; i<this.length; i++){
            if(this[i]===obj){
                return i;
            }
        }
     return -1;
   };
}
```

I can't really take credit for this.  It's probably a fairly generic piece of code I found in some tutorial or one of Doug Crockford's articles. I'm quite sure someone will come along with a better way of writing it.

I find working in Firefox is a good place to start because you can install the Firebug console and get a better idea where things are going wrong.  I admit that doesn't solve cross-browser problems, but at least it allows you to get a start on your project.

This little piece of code will ensure you can use the indexOf method to find where a given value is in a one-dimensional array. With your 2-dimensional array, each element in the outer array is an array not a single value. I'm going to do a little test to see exactly how that works and get back to you, unless someone else comes in with a better answer.

I hope this at least gets you started.

UPDATE
Assuming you have a browser that implements Array.indexOf, I've tried every which way to pass one of the array elements in your outer array.

```
alert(array.indexOf([3,56]))
alert(array.indexOf("3,56"))
```

just return -1.

Oddly,

```
alert(array.indexOf(array[1]))
```

correctly returns 1. But you need to know the index of the inner array to get the index!  I can't see a way of passing an array to the indexOf method.

Comment: I was going to mention this. I've been in positions in the past where I've been tearing my hair out over this. +1

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code, it is working

```js
 var array = [[2, 45], [3, 56], [5, 67], [8, 98], [6, 89], [9, 89], [5, 67]];
array.map((x, index) => {
    if (x.includes(56)) {
        console.log(index);
    }
})
```